# Why doesn't cairo translate text?

Tags: haskell, cairo

In the following program I am drawing some small boxes with letters in them using `cairo-0.12.2`. Unfortunately, when I use the `translate` function to move the user-space origin, the rectangle is translated but the text isn't.

```
import Graphics.Rendering.Cairo

main = withSVGSurface "test.svg" 600 600 
  (`renderWith` draw)

draw = do
  color white
  rectangle 0 0 600 600
  fill
  newPath
  color black
  translate 300 300
  drawSortBox
  translate 200 200
  drawSortBox
  stroke

drawSortBox = do
  showText "V  Ʌ"
  a <- textExtents "V  Ʌ"
  rectangle (textExtentsXbearing a - 2) (textExtentsYbearing a - 2) (textExtentsWidth a / 2 + 2) (textExtentsHeight a + 4)
  rectangle (textExtentsXbearing a - 2) (textExtentsYbearing a - 2) (textExtentsWidth a + 4) (textExtentsHeight a + 4)

color (a,b,c) = setSourceRGB a b c

white = (255,255,255)
black =(0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation, `showText` draws its text starting at the current location. `translate` moves the origin, but not the current location. You must use `moveTo` instead of `translate` to choose the location of your text. (The fact that `translate` happened to work for the first call is related to the fact that `newPath` removes the current location.)